# MLE for gaussian, finding $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

"Assume that a dataset $x_1,\ldots, x_N$ consisting of $N$ points was sampled from a Gaussian distribution, i.e., $X_i \sim N(\mu; \sigma^2)$ for some unknown $- \infty < \mu < \infty$ and unknown $0 < \sigma^2 < \infty$. Also, assume that the $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed (iid). Find the maximum likelihood estimate of the Gaussian mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$
(and show that the critical point obtained is, at least, a local maximum)" -exercise $2.8$, A first course in machine learning, second edition.

I'm currently trying to solve the exercise above, however it's proving hard for me, nad i would love some help / a reference solution to the exercise.

So first i'll define the log-likelihood as:
$$\log L = -\frac{N}{2}\log2\pi-N \log \sigma - \frac {1}{2 \sigma^2}\sum_{n=1}^N(t_n - w^Tx_n$$

I then find the derivative and set it equal to $0$ so:

$$\frac{\log L} w = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{n=1}^N x_nt_n - x_n x_n^T w=0$$

which can then be rewritten as:

$$\frac{\log L} w = \frac 1 {\sigma^2}(X^T t-X^t Xw)=0,$$ and i can then solve for $w$ and get:
$$w = (X^TX)^{-1} X^T t$$

After this point i get stuck, and unsure of how to find MLE for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, aswell as how to show that the critical point is at least a local maximum.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused - why do you have $t_n, w$ and $x_n$? I think in your case, you don't need them as both $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are real numbers and not vectors - that is, you have normal, not multivariate distribution.

Anyway, you are not the right track:

$$\ell(\mu,\sigma^2)=-\frac{n}{2}\log(2\pi\sigma^2)-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum(x_i-\mu)^2$$

Differentiate with respect to $\mu$ and set to $0$ (under the usual circumstances your MLE will satisfy this):

$$\frac{\sum(x_i-\hat\mu)}{\sigma^2}=0$$
which is equivalent to
$$\hat\mu=\frac{\sum x_i}{n}=\bar x$$

To get the MLE for $\sigma^2$ differentiate with respect to $\sigma^2$, set to $0$ and plug $\hat\mu$ instead of $\mu$ for estimation to get:

$$-\frac{n}{2\sigma^2}+\frac{1}{2\sigma^4}\sum(x_i-\hat\mu)^2=0$$

which is equivalent to:

$$\hat\sigma^2=\frac{\sum(x_i-\hat\mu)^2}{n}$$

The answer you get is when you do linear modeling and you want to find out the MLE for the vector of coefficients, so I suppose you've come across those?

Comment: The reason i have $t_n, w$ and $x_n$ was because i saw that by taking the partial derivative one could find $\sigma ^2$ by (assuming $w = \hat{w}$):

$$\hat{\sigma} ^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}(t_n - x^T\hat{w})^2$$

or am i on a completely wrong track?

Comment: I'm still pretty sure you are thinking about linear modelling since this is exaclty what it's done in that case. You can post the fill question if you want to

Comment: Arhh sorry yes this is for linear modelling, and this is the entire exercise description, or do u mean something else by fill question?

Comment: In a linear model, you deal with vectors rather than real numbers so it's a bit different. In that case, your big vector $\underline{y}=(y_1 \dots y_n)$ has multivariate distribution with mean $\mu$ - a vector and variance matrix - $\sigma^2$. Then what you've estimated is in fact, the vector of coefficients. Each mean  equals $x_{i}^T\hat\omega$ where $x_i$ is a vector of observations, hence the mean $\mu$ is the vector of means or alternatively, the design matrix times the vector of coefficients. Similarly, taking derivative with respect to $\sigma^2$ gives the MLE for $\sigma^2$

Comment: I'm not very good at explaining, but in that case you have to think vectorwise, not scalarwise